# Find a pattern and surround it with quotes

Tags: regex, django, sed, grep, pattern-matching

So I'm upgrading from Django 1.3 > 1.4 and there's a requirement for patterns of `{% url app:X:Y %}` to be `{% url "app:X:Y" %}`. There are 493 instances of this pattern in the project, thus I'm trying to find how to automate it.

To be clear there could be further words within the brackets but it's always the one after `"{% url "` and up until the next space I have to wrap.

I checked out `sed` but I'm not sure how to get that working correctly with `grep`. Does anyone have an example of something that would work here?

See it with a sample file:

This file has 2 urls but it should only catch the 2nd one (the grep isn't really the issue, it's the replacing.) This file should be the exact same except `{% url admin:index %}` should be `{% url "admin:index" %}`

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
   {% load i18n %}
   {% load url from future %}

  {% if not is_popup %}
  {% block breadcrumbs %}
  <div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="{% url admin:index %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
  &rsaquo;
  {% for app in app_list %}
```

This is a grep that finds all cases, but it fails on ones that already have quotes around them and of course it does not actually edit them `grep -r "{% url .* " .`

Comment: could you provide some sample input and desired output? can this be multi-lined?

Comment: Done, the should I be using sed to replace the text?

Comment: nice! you just missed how the output should look like : )

Comment: Sorry there you go, I did have an example up top but I see how it's easier to read now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the regular expression to this form: `{% url <things> %}`. By enclosing groups in parentheses, we can print them back. Note `<things>` is a set of `A:B:C:...:Z`, that is, something we define as "anything up to a space".

All together:

```
sed 's/\({% url \)\([^ ]*\)\( %}\)/\1"\2"\3/' file
```

You can do this to all the files in a given folder by saying:

```
for file in *
do
    sed '...' "$file"
done
```

If you say `sed -i.bak '...' file`, you will get the files edited in-place, with a backup `file.bak` created (it is always good to do so, just in case!).

#### Test

With your given file stored in `a`, it returns...

```
$ sed 's/\({% url \)\([^ ]*\)\( %}\)/\1"\2"\3/' a
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% if not is_popup %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url "admin:index" %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo;
{% for app in app_list %}
```

Comment: Thanks! And will that do all files in a folder for example?

Comment: Sorry, as to my original qs. Will this work on A:X AND A:X:Y:Z AND A:X:Y. Your one seems to require that it be only of the form A:X. Sorry if I was unclear but I did say it needs to be "always the one after "{% url " and up until the next space I have to wrap."... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do and I did I had thought, it obviously just wasn't clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: @bungleofsketches no problem. Edited my answer to cover the final solution. Cheers!